# Simply iterate over uchar starting from '0'

Tags: c++, loops, callback, char, keyboard

I'm just trying to do this as a loop :

```
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('0', [&](){
        buttons.at(0)->pressed();
    });
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('1', [&](){
        buttons.at(1)->pressed();
    });
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('2', [&](){
        buttons.at(2)->pressed();
    });
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('3', [&](){
        buttons.at(3)->pressed();
    });
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('4', [&](){
        buttons.at(4)->pressed();
    });
```

The previous sample work perfectly.

So I basicly try this :

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
        keyboardHandler.register_callback('0' + i, [&](){
            buttons.at(i)->pressed();
        });
    }
```

which give me the following execution exception when I press the '0', '1', ... '4' on my keyboard :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Here is my register_callback method :

```
    void register_callback(unsigned char key, std::function<void()> callback){
        _registered_callback[key] = callback ;
    }
```

PS : I do not think the problem is coming from deeper in the code because the test without looping work perfectly.

Comment: You need to capture i by value not reference

Comment: @MikeVine Sounds like an answer :)

Comment: Holy shit ! Was that, TY i should go to bed ^^

Comment: You should explicitly specify the names you want to capture by reference, when you are storing the lambda for later use.

Comment: Indeed, it look more efficient

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @cigien, you need to capture the loop counter variable by reference in the lambda. I'm pretty sure that capturing something by reference which goes out of scope and has its lifetime end before the lambda which captures it is a lifetime issue and is UB (but I'm not a C++ language lawyer).

```cpp
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
    keyboardHandler.register_callback('0' + i, [i](){
        buttons.at(i)->pressed();
    });
}
```